# Citing literature reference as a statement of purpose title

Tags: citations, statement-of-purpose, citation-style

I'm currently putting the finishing touches on a few grad school applications, and some of them require that my statement of purpose has a title. For one reason or another, I decided that the title of my essay should be a meaningful, yet obscure quote from my favorite novel.

How do I cite this? Including an entire bibliography seems like severe overkill, but not citing the book at all seems.. careless. I've currently just provided a link to a website where they've published only the relevant page of said book, but even this seems lazy! Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: A footnote would be pretty typical, with a standard format citation.